# Meaning of %o% in R

Tags: r, operator-keyword

I encountered the following in R:

```
x=x+y%o%c(1.5,1.5)
```

I am wondering what is the meaning of `%o%` here. I tried googling but didn't have much luck

Comment: Which language are you talking about???

Comment: `?'%o%'` outer product of arrays

Comment: @KarthikRocky asking about R, as shown in the title and the tag.

Comment: I never know there s a language exists like that.. just Googled. Interesting. Thanks @Gregor

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a number of shortcuts in R that use the `%...%` notation. `%o%` is the outer product of arrays

```
> 1:3 %o% 1:3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
```

There are a number of others, my most used is `%in%`:

```
3 %in% c(1,2,3,4) #TRUE
5 %in% c(1,2,3,4) #FALSE
3.4 %in% c(1,2,3,4) #FALSE
```

There are a few others, I don't know them all off the top of my head. But when you encounter them, you can check for documentation by using backticks around the `%o%` like `` ?`%o%` ``, or quotes `?'%o%'` (or `?"%o%"`).

They are obviously difficult to google because of the percent sign.

Comment: You can also create your own infix operators (as they're called), as shown in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441092/creating-an-infix-between-operator-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

An intuition. `%o%` is outer product, look at the example, it returns a matrix. 
`a[1] * b` is the first row of matrix, 
`a[2] * b` is the second row of the matrix.

```r
> a = c(1, 2, 3)
> b = c(0, 2, 4)
> a %o% b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    4
[2,]    0    4    8
[3,]    0    6   12
```